# Extract data from a firebird database with python fdb module

Tags: python, firebird

I'm trying to read the data from a Firebird database, created by Firebird version 2.5, by using the FDB module from Python. Unsuccessfully.
I have a Python v3.7.3 on a Windows10 64 bits system.

I am able to connect to the database and read the names of its tables:

```py
con_1 = fdb.connect(dsn='C:/Prova_Archi.eft', user='sysdba', password='masterkey')  
schema_1 = fdb.schema.Schema()  
schema_1.bind(con2)  
print (schema_1.tables[57].name)  ===>  TUtenti
```

I am also able to read, for a given table, the name of its columns and indices:

```
print ([i.name for i in con_1.schema.get_table(schema_1.tables[57].name).columns][0]) ===> ...  
print ([i.name for i in con_1.schema.get_table(schema_1.tables[n].name).indices][r]) ===> ...
```

However, I am not able to extract the data!

When I try this:

```
cur_1 = con_1.cursor()  
cur_1.execute("select * from 'TUtenti'")
```

I am given the following error:

> ===> DatabaseError: ("Error while preparing SQL statement:\n- SQLCODE: -104\n- Dynamic SQL Error\n- SQL error code = -104\n- Token unknown - line 1, column 15\n- 'TUtenti'", -104, 335544569)

Suggestions are highly welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that single quotes delimit a string literal, not an object name (e.g. a table name). To quote an object name you need to use double quotes, so use:

```py
cur_1.execute('select * from "TUtenti"')
```

Comment: Little bit frustrating discovering to have spent hours trying to fix an issue which was so simple to fix ...... However that simple detail is not mentioned (at least any clearly) in all the documents I read. So thanks again.

Comment: @GgF Section [Identifiers](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-structure-identifiers) in the Firebird 2.5 Language Reference, and specifically [Rules for Delimited Object Identifiers](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-structure-identifiers-delim). BTW: Using double quotes for delimited (quoted) identifiers is standard SQL syntax, it is not specific to Firebird.

Comment: @GgF there is a common approach: take the thing that works and look how it was done. 1) Take any database IDE (IBExpert, FlameRobin, dbWeaver, etc), create the table with that strange a name, use the IDE tools to make filtered query, read the query source text; 2) take FBExport ( or was it FBExtract ? ) tool, read it sources, find the query generating function, borrow the correct way to do it

Comment: So, once you've got here. What do you do to read the data. I followed all the steps but when I run  cur_1.execute('select * from "TUtenti"') , I just get the follwing <fdb.fbcore.Cursor at 0x2b213a0fe20>.  ¿What should I do to get the info? thanks

Comment: @GustavoZárate The cursor object allows you to fetch the data of the query. See [Python DBAPI](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), and [FDB documentation](https://fdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), or [pyfirebirdsql documentation](https://pyfirebirdsql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), or [firebird-driver documentation](https://firebird-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)