# Get data from tables in Firebird database

Tags: python, sql, firebird, fdb

I'm trying to get the data from the tables in a Firebird database. So far, I've managed to make a successful connection and to get the table names. Following some other posts here, I've managed to "select" (whatever that means and implies) with cursor function the database I want to read, but I haven't been able to retrieve the information and use it in Pandas, which is what I want.

This is my code, I hope you help me with this is issue:

```
#Connection is made
con=fdb.connect(dsn=r'C:\table.FDB',user='SYSD', password='key')

#I don't know what this is for, but it helps me get the table names and somehow I think I'm getting closer.

schema1=fdb.schema.Schema()
schema1.bind(con)
for i in range(len(schema1.tables)):
    print(schema1.tables[i].name)
    
#This I got it from this post that said it would retrieve the data, but I just don't know how to get it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64826318/extract-data-from-a-firebird-database-with-python-fdb-module 

cur1=con.cursor()
cur1.execute('select * from "INVE04"')

#I get the following:
<fdb.fbcore.Cursor at 0x2b213a0fe20>
```

What should I do next to read the data? I'm not familiar with Firebird, so consulting the documentation I couldn’t find any method or way to read/extract/consume the data in each table. Am I going the right way here?

Comment: `fdb` implements the [Python Database API 2.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) and offers a [usage guide](https://fdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage-guide.html).  Do either of those help?

Answer (score 1):

I used the Firebird ODBC driver to make queries. In case of Python >=3.8 the other official python package for FB is working well

```
$ pip install firebird-driver
```

This driver uses new Firebird OO API provided by fbclient library (.so/.dll)
and works like mentioned by [mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466862/mark-rotteveel) by iterating over `cur.fetchall()`
and also like [rodrigo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22678817/rodrigo-brugalli) suggests except that shortcut functions for `pandas.DataFrame` might even be more convenient and can reduce code like so:

```
import pandas as pd
from firebird.driver import connect, driver_config

driver_config.fb_client_library.value = ODBC_LIB_PATH
con = connect(VARIO_DB, user='ODBC', password='odbc', role='VF_USER_RO')

# IMPORTANT: python str uses "" while sql query uses ''
sql = "SELECT some_col FROM some_table WHERE another_col = 'interesting'"

df = pd.read_sql(sql, con)
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

The Firebird FDB driver implements the [Python DB API 2.0 (PEP-249)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/). How you retrieve rows is standardized in this API, and is also documented in the [FDB documentation](https://fdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Specifically, [Executing SQL Statements](https://fdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage-guide.html#executing-sql-statements) shows 3 different ways to process query results:

> ```py
> import fdb
>
> con = fdb.connect(dsn='/temp/test.db', user='sysdba', password='masterkey')
>
> cur = con.cursor()
> SELECT = "select name, year_released from languages order by year_released"
>
> # 1. Using built-in support for iteration protocol to iterate over the rows available from the cursor,
> # unpacking the resulting sequences to yield their elements (name, year_released):
> cur.execute(SELECT)
> for (name, year_released) in cur:
>     print '%s has been publicly available since %d.' % (name, year_released)
> # or alternatively you can take an advantage of cur.execute returning self.
> for (name, year_released) in cur.execute(SELECT):
>     print '%s has been publicly available since %d.' % (name, year_released)
>
> # 2. Equivalently using fetchall():
> # This is potentially dangerous if result set is huge, as the whole result set is first materialized
> # as list and then used for iteration.
> cur.execute(SELECT)
> for row in cur.fetchall():
>     print '%s has been publicly available since %d.' % (row[0], row[1])
>
> # 3. Using mapping-iteration rather than sequence-iteration:
> cur.execute(SELECT)
> for row in cur.itermap():
>     print '%(name)s has been publicly available since %(year_released)d.' % row
> ```

In short, you can iterate over the cursor itself (sequence iteration, option 1), you can fetch all rows into a list using `fetchall()` (option 2), or you can use `itermap()` (mapping-iteration, option 3).

There are additional options (like repeatedly calling `fetchone()`, or fetching in batches using `fetchmany()`).

Comment: thanks a lot. I think that i'm lost cause I have no idea of what a cursor means or how it works. I mean, it's so different of what i've done before. It seems like im using a mouse and I just cant find out how it works. Can you help me understand?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem recent. I think this code can help you.

```
import fdb
import pandas as pd

con = fdb.connect(dsn='/temp/test.db', user='sysdba', password='masterkey')

cur = con.cursor()
result = cur.execute(" SELECT = select name, year_released from languages order by year_released")

result = result.fatchall()

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
```